# How can I stop a dead tree's roots from popping up in the grass?

Tags: lawn, tree-removal

I dug up a tree a year ago and the roots seem to still be spreading under ground.  Every once in a while I will see it sprout above ground.   I keep pulling it out but it comes back.  How do I kill the root forever without hurting the grass?

Answer (score 2):

Just keep using your lawnmower.  Set the mowing height a little lower for the problem area. If you told us what kind of tree we could provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Brush Be Gone](http://www.gardenguides.com/132346-brush-gone-vs-roundup.html), which is selective for [dicots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicotyledon) over [monocots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocotyledon), should prove useful. That said, some tree types have roots that can live underground without foliage for many years. Killing the thing may well be a multi-year project.

Answer (score 1):

Put epsom salt on the roots. Multiple applications. Another option depending on there size is poke a few drill holes in the roots and poor in some high nitrogen fertilizer. The decomposers in the soil feed of the nitrogen and process the wood much faster then usual.